# PowerShell: Opening 2 instances of MS Edge on different monitors

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge

I am trying to open 2 different websites in 2 separate windows of MS Edge. I have 2 PowerShell scripts as follows:

```
$edgeExePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" # Update the path if necessary

$monitorIndex = 0 # Index of the target monitor (0 for the first monitor, 1 for the second, and so on)

$url = "https://www.example.com/"

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

if (Test-Path $edgeExePath) {
    $screenBounds = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens[$monitorIndex].Bounds
    $windowPosition = "$($screenBounds.Left),$($screenBounds.Top)"
    $windowSize = "$($screenBounds.Width),$($screenBounds.Height)"
    $edgeArgs = "--window-position=$windowPosition --window-size=$windowSize --start-fullscreen --new-window $url"
    
    Start-Process -FilePath $edgeExePath -ArgumentList $edgeArgs
} else {
    Write-Host "Microsoft Edge is not installed or the path is incorrect."
}
```

(2x with a different $monitorIndex)

Now, if i run both of these scripts, whatever window comes first, the second window goes to the same monitor...
If I remove the "--start-fullscreen" flag from 1 script, both windows still start in fullscreen or both do not start in fullscreen, depending on which script is run first.

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Edge Version: Version 114.0.1823.37 (Official build) (64-bit)

**NOTE**: I have the "boost start-up" option disabled, as this prevents "--start-fullscreen" from taking effect entirely

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it by passing a unique "--user-data-dir=" for each window I want to open.